# Translating float index interpolation from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, interpolation

For example, I have a index array

```
ax = [0, 0.2, 2] #start from index 0: python
```

and matrix `I`

```
I= 
10    20    30    40    50
10    20    30    40    50
10    20    30    40    50
10    20    30    40    50
10    20    30    40    50
```

In MATLAB, by running this code

```matlab
[gx, gy] = meshgrid([1,1.2,3], [1,1.2,3]);
I = [10:10:50];
I = vertcat(I,I,I,I,I)
SI = interp2(I,gx,gy,'bilinear');
```

The resulting `SI` is

```matlab
SI =
10    12    30
10    12    30
10    12    30
```

---

I tried to do the same interpolation in Python, using NumPy. I first interpolate row-wise, then column-wise

```py
import numpy as np
ax = np.array([0.0, 0.2, 2.0])
ay = np.array([0.0, 0.2, 2.0])
I = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50]])
I = np.concatenate((I,I,I,I,I), axis=0)
r_idx = np.arange(1, I.shape[0]+1)
c_idx = np.arange(1, I.shape[1]+1)
  
I_row = np.transpose(np.array([np.interp(ax, r_idx, I[:,x]) for x in range(0,I.shape[0])]))
I_col = np.array([np.interp(ay, c_idx, I_row[y,:]) for y in range(0, I_row.shape[0])])

SI = I_col
```

However, the resulting `SI` is

```py
SI =
10    10    20
10    10    20
10    10    20
```

Why are my results using Python different from those using MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you over-corrected yourself by passing from MATLAB to Python, as shown by your first code excerpt.

```
ax = [0, 0.2, 2] #start from index 0: python
```

In numpy logic this sequence does not represents the indexes but the coordinate
for the function to interpolate.
Since you already take care of incrementing the coordinate to be compatible with matlab here:

```
r_idx = np.arange(1, I.shape[0]+1)
c_idx = np.arange(1, I.shape[1]+1)
```

You can reuse the same interpolation coordinate that you used in Matlab:

```
ax = [1,1.2,3]
```

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
ax = np.array([1.0, 1.2, 3.0])
ay = np.array([1.0, 1.2, 3.0])
I = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50]])
I = np.concatenate((I,I,I,I,I), axis=0)
r_idx = np.arange(1, I.shape[0]+1)
c_idx = np.arange(1, I.shape[1]+1)

I_row = np.transpose(np.array([np.interp(ax, r_idx, I[:,x]) for x in range(0,I.shape[
0])]))
I_col = np.array([np.interp(ay, c_idx, I_row[y,:]) for y in range(0, I_row.shape[0])]
)

SI = I_col
```

and result:

```
array([[10., 12., 30.],
       [10., 12., 30.],
       [10., 12., 30.]])
```

#### Explanation about the bug

Since `ax` represented coordinates the first two values `0.0` and `0.2` were before the first coordinate of `r_idx`.
According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), the interpolation will default to I[:,x][0].